# how to apply long only add.distribution parameterset in quantStrat - simpleError in param.combo[[param.label]]

Tags: r, quantstrat

I am applying similar add.distribution rule as in the luxor-demo while my strategy has only a long position.

The whole strategy works, but when applying a parameterset I get following error:

> TakeProfitLONG 47          0.047
>
> TakeProfitLONG 47          0.047 result of evaluating expression:
>
> simpleError in param.combo[[param.label]]: subscript out of bounds
>
> got results for task 47 numValues: 47, numResults: 47, stopped: FALSE
>   returning status FALSE evaluation # 48: $param.combo

I am trying to run a distribution on a simple takeProfit rule (get same result from stopLoss or trailingStop):

```
.use.takeProfit = TRUE
.takeprofit <- 2.0/100 # actual
.TakeProfit = seq(0.1, 4.8, length.out=48)/100 # parameter set for optimization

## take-profit
add.rule(strategy.st, name = 'ruleSignal',
         arguments=list(sigcol='signal.gt.zero' , sigval=TRUE,
                        replace=FALSE,
                        orderside='long',
                        ordertype='limit', 
                        tmult=TRUE, 
                        threshold=quote(.takeprofit),
                        TxnFees=.txnfees,
                        orderqty='all',
                        orderset='ocolong'
         ),
         type='chain', 
         parent='EnterLONG',
         label='TakeProfitLONG',
         enabled=.use.takeProfit
)
```

I am adding the distribution as follows:

```
add.distribution(strategy.st,
                 paramset.label = 'TakeProfit',
                 component.type = 'chain',
                 component.label = 'TakeProfitLONG',
                 variable = list(threshold = .TakeProfit),
                 label = 'TakeProfitLONG'
)
```

and apply the set:

```
results <- apply.paramset(strategy.st, paramset.label='TakeProfit', portfolio.st=portfolio.st, account.st=account.st, nsamples=.nsamples, verbose=TRUE)
```

From my limited debugging it seems that the parameterset is a simple vector whereas in the apply.paramset following function fails:

```
results <- fe %dopar% { ... }
```

Here I am too new to R as i am only 4 weeks looking into this, but possibly a call to:

```
install.param.combo <- function(strategy, param.combo, paramset.label)
```

might cause the error?

Have to apologize as I am to new, but did anyone encounter this or could help how to apply a distribution to only one item in a long only strategy?

Many thanks in advance!

**EDIT 1:** SessionInfo()

```
R version 3.1.2 (2014-10-31)
Platform: i486-pc-linux-gnu (32-bit)

locale:
[1] C

attached base packages:
[1] stats     graphics  grDevices utils     datasets  methods   base     

other attached packages:
 [1] lattice_0.20-29               iterators_1.0.7               downloader_0.3
 [4] quantstrat_0.9.1665           foreach_1.4.2                 blotter_0.9.1644
 [7] PerformanceAnalytics_1.4.3574 FinancialInstrument_1.2.0     quantmod_0.4-3
[11] TTR_0.22-0.1                  xts_0.9-7                     zoo_1.7-12

loaded via a namespace (and not attached):
[1] codetools_0.2-9 compiler_3.1.2  digest_0.6.7    grid_3.1.2      tools_3.1.2
```

Comment: This looks similar to [bug #5776](https://r-forge.r-project.org/tracker/index.php?func=detail&aid=5776&group_id=316&atid=1269). Please add the output from `sessionInfo()` to your question.

Comment: Hi Joshua. Thanks for the reply and it seems to be related to the bug [#5776](https://r-forge.r-project.org/tracker/index.php?func=detail&aid=5776&group_id=316&atid=1269) although i did not get any valid output with a single parameter - just the "simpleError" message in the question title. Using two parameters seems to work fine. Was so focused on getting at least one parameter running that I never thought of fully replicating the example with two parameters.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This is the same bug as [# 5776](https://r-forge.r-project.org/tracker/index.php?func=detail&aid=5776&group_id=316&atid=1269). It was fixed for "signal" component types, but not for "chain". It should now be fixed as of [revision 1669 on R-Forge](https://r-forge.r-project.org/scm/viewvc.php?view=rev&root=blotter&revision=1669).

Comment: Just updated to revision 1669 and it works perfectly fine for a single  parameter. Many thanks for the update/fix!

Comment: @Aylon: glad to help. Thanks for the report!